# How do I echo the number of items in an array?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

A total newbie question I know.

I'm sing Zend framework, and sending an array from the controller:

```
$this->view->googleArray = $viewFeedArray;
```

In the view, I have a foreach loop that is populating a table with the array contents.

```
<?php 
foreach($this->googleArray as $row) { ?>
  <tr>          
    <td><?php echo $row['when']; ?></td>
    ...
    ...
  </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

It all works fine.  At the top of the table, I want to list the number of items in the array.

Something like (which doesn't work):

```
 <?php echo $this->googleArray->totalResults; ?> event(s) found
```

How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tried this?

```
<?php echo count($this->googleArray); ?> event(s) found
```

Comment: sweet!  Worked great!  I've been working on this for over an hour.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joel: Here is a list of available array functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php Can come handy. You should always read the documentation.